# Scrapy Incremental crawls to filter duplicate items

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I would like to run Scrapy periodically to get all new content. Yielded items are stored in a database. What would be the best way to verify that, when Scrapy crawls again, that already yielded items are not stored as duplicates?

Would giving items a hash be a good way to verify this? I don't want to end up having duplicate items in my database.

Thanks!

Comment: load all items into a list before spider starts, and at the time of yielding, just check if it exists in that list or not

Comment: Best solution depends on couple of things. How do you store items in database? Do you store them in spider class or do you use pipeline? Do you want to skip items you already have altogether, or you'd better like to update them in database (in case they changed). What database do you use? After answering those question, the best solution would be clearer.

Comment: Hello @TomášLinhart. I use the relational database MySQL to store the data. I use the items in an item class and use the pipeline to process crawled data and to export these to the database. I am not yet sure whether skipping or updating the item would be the best option. But I can imagine that the overhead of checking the database slows down the crawler, doesn't it?

Comment: If you use a pipeline, than checking the database for duplicate goes there as well. That won't affect crawling performance.

Comment: I understand. Do I have to setup scrapy to perform database verification, or is this built in? Furthermore, does this functionality also apply to MongoDB?

Answer (score 2):

If you are scraping items simultaneously between different crawls,checking the DB for duplicate in pipeline that is referred by Tomáš Linhart is a make-sense choice.

Otherwise,I think performing duplication process at scrapy scope is better alternative.
For example [scrapy-deltafetch](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-deltafetch) provided by the community,which filter duplicate items in spider middleware for incremental(delta) crawls.

DeltaFetch works by intercepting every Item and Request objects generated in spider callbacks. For Items, it computes the related request identifier (a.k.a. fingerprint) and stores it into a local database(nested). For Requests, Deltafetch computes the request fingerprint and drops the request if it already exists in the database.

After you install and configure this plugin properly.Then run crawler and take a look at the Stats that Scrapy logged at the end.You can see the new-add items that is about deltafetch.

```
2017-12-25 16:36:17 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'deltafetch/skipped': 88,
 'deltafetch/stored': 262,
 'downloader/request_count': 286,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
  ...
 'item_scraped_count': 262,
  ...
}
```